# Merge, join, and concatenate data with Power Query

Tags: powerquery

For example, I have this data:

```
Name   | m / f / x
Peter  | m
Jack   | m
Mary   | f
Tim    | m
Olivia | f
Cindy  | f
Walter | m
Ronald | m
Patty  | x
```

And I want to use Power Query to do the following:

```
m / f / x | Surname
m         | Peter, Jack, Tim, Walter, Ronald
f         | Mary, Olivia, Cindy
x         | Patty

I tried a lot but did not get a result. The best but still wrong result:
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook () {[Name = "Table1"]} [Content],
    # "Modified Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes (Source, {{"Name", type text}, {"m / f / x", type text}}),
    # "Renamed columns" = Table.RenameColumns (# "Modified type", {{"m / f / x", "m, f or x"}}),
    # "Grouped rows" = Table.Group (# "renamed columns", {"m, f or x"}, {{"sex", each _, type table [name = text, m, f or x = text] }}),
    # "Added custom column" = Table.AddColumn (# "Grouped rows", "Custom", each Table.TransformColumns (# "Grouped rows", {"sex", each Text.Combine ([Name], "|") })),
    # "Advanced Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn (# "Added custom column", "Custom", {"sex"}, {"Custom.sex"})
in
    # "Advanced Custom"
I'm sure this line / formula (editor) is wrong:
Table.TransformColumns (# "grouped rows", {"sex", each Text.Combine ([name], "|")})
```

What is the correct code?

Gladly a reference to an already existing solution (which I searched but did not find). Many of the examples in the Microsoft M reference are, in my view, unfamiliar to practice and incomprehensible to me, because I'm accessing existing fields in a query rather than constructing individual cell values. - I would understand it better, if you write me not only the complete M code but also the important command lines with the formula. With an age of more than 70 years, the ability to abstract is no longer so pronounced ...

Thank you says
Guenther

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    group = Table.Group(Source, {"m / f / x""}, {"Names", each Text.Combine([Name], ", ")})
in
    group
```

[image]